# How can i get into the value inside of an html <tr> object

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

So i have this code. I want to send the data inside of my html inputs to the controllers parameters. In my jquery i have a line that looks like this
var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
But i have no clue how to get into the values of each input inside the currentRow Object how can i do that or do you maybe know a better way to do this?

```
 // my html
@foreach (var discount in Model.DiscountList)
        {

            <tr>
                <td>@Html.TextBox("codeTextBox", discount.Code) </td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="freeShippingCheckBox" id="freeShippingCheckBox" checked="@discount.FreeShipping" /> </td>
                @if (discount.isTwoForThree == true)
                {
                    <td><input type="tel" value="Ta 3 betala för 2" readonly /></td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td><input type="number" value="@discount.PercentOffPrice"/></td>
                }
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="activeCheckBox" name="activeCheckBox" checked="@discount.Active" /></td>
                <td><input type="datetime" value="@discount.CreatedDate" readonly /></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Radera" class="fa fa-remove" data-url="@Url.Action("DeleteDiscountCode","Discount",new { id= discount.Id})" />
                    <input type="button" value="Uppdatera" class="fa fa-update" data-url="@Url.Action("UpdateDiscount","Discount",new { id= discount.Id, })" />
                    <input type="button" value="Produkter" class="fa fa-products" />
                </td>
                <input id="@discount.Id.ToString()" type="hidden" value="@discount.Id" />
            </tr>
        }


//my jquery  
          $(".fa-update").on("click", function () {
            var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");

            console.log(currentRow.children("#freeShippingCheckBox").val());
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to edit this discount code?"))
            {

                $.post($(this).data("url"), function (data) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("DeleteUser","Discount")',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: "freeShipping=..........???????????",
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data) {

                            }
                            location.reload();
                        }
                    });
                    location.reload();
                    alert("Deleted");
                })
            }

        });



 //my controller
    [HttpPost]
    public void UpdateDiscount(int id, bool freeShipping, int percentOfPrice, bool active)
    {
        Service.DiscountService.UpdateDiscount(id, freeShipping, percentOfPrice, active);
    }
```

Comment: `.html()`, `.text()`...

Comment: If you give `name` attributes to your inputs they will automatically post, but your controller would have to change and you would have to come up with a naming strategy as they are created in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal is:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".fa-update").on("click", function (e) {
    var data = {};
    var currentRowParams = $(this).closest("tr").find('input').each(function(index, element) {
      var name = element.name ? element.name : 'undefined' + index;
      data[name] = element.value || '';
    });
    var x =  JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(x);
    
    //
    // If instead you want the params in a traditional GET
    //
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.TextBox("codeTextBox", discount.Code) </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="freeShippingCheckBox" id="freeShippingCheckBox" checked="@discount.FreeShipping" /> </td>
        <td><input type="tel" value="Ta 3 betala for 2" readonly /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="activeCheckBox" name="activeCheckBox" checked="@discount.Active" /></td>
        <td><input type="datetime" value="@discount.CreatedDate" readonly /></td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Radera" class="fa fa-remove" data-url="@Url.Action("DeleteDiscountCode","Discount",new { id= discount.Id})" />
            <input type="button" value="Uppdatera" class="fa fa-update" data-url="@Url.Action("UpdateDiscount","Discount",new { id= discount.Id, })" />
            <input type="button" value="Produkter" class="fa fa-products" />
        </td>
        <input id="@discount.Id.ToString()" type="hidden" value="@discount.Id" />
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: the problem with this code is that the the boolean values return only "on" instead of "true/false"

Comment: If you apply the .serialize() the boolean values are exactly on/ off. In any case it's not hard to convert these values to true/ false. Thanks

Comment: they dont become on or of they always get on

Answer (score 1):

You can access a value via `.html()`. As Vijai said, you can use serialize to make it a POST array like (&=, etc) format assuming you have a structured form. Or, to stay similar to your original code, you can just pass as usual JSON. like

```
data:{shippingInfo: "value", moreInfo: "blahblah"}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use a `<form id="formID" ...>` tag around yours inputs and use `$("#formID").serialize()` in the Ajax method if you are not doing processing of the input value in the View. Refer this sample link : [Submit form using AJAX and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425095/submit-form-using-ajax-and-jquery)

```
$.post($(this).data("url"), function (data) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("DeleteUser","Discount")',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: $("#formID").serialize(),
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data) {

                            }
                            location.reload();
                        }
                    });
```